how i create trendline on time series data in vegalite
i trying to create a bar chart along with it trend line in vegalite
but trendline is not same as when i used same data in excel it then trendline line goes in upward (increasing) but on same data it goes in downward (decreasing) direction in vegalite  
but on same data vegalite trendline (regression) is different
i am not getting why ?

EDITOR LINK

The data is different - just look at your 4th bar

When sorting the date column in Excel from 202102 to 202307 (ascending) Excel's linear trendline looks exaclty the same as with Vega-Lite

Thanks for figure out it
